# Highlighting a substring in a string

Tags: reactjs, regex, jsx

I'm trying to highlight a matched substring in a searchable array of strings. I'm pretty close I think, just that last bit is not working.

I display an array of strings. When I type in an input the substrings in the array are supposed to get highlighted (using `<mark></mark>`) when matched with the input. The matching works ok but instead of highlighted text I get `[object Object]` instead.
So this is the part of code in question (it sits in Jsx inside a `.map()` method:

```
<div>
  {item.matched.length > 0
    ? item.name.replace(new RegExp(inputText, 'gi'), (match) => (
        <mark>{match}</mark>
      ))
    : item.name}
</div>
```

The `item` is an element of the array that I'm mapping and has two properties: `name` & `matched`. `matched` is either empty or contains the typed search pattern if part or all of `name` matches it.
And this is what I'm getting when typing into text box:

[image]

So clearly the search and match work correctly and look what I get: `[object Object]` instead of highlighted search pattern.
I've tried to return a template string, like that *backquote*`<mark>${match}</mark>`*backquote*, but that results in displaying `<mark>a</mark>` in my example.

So I'm at loss here and any constructive feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we should render at in html

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: (item.matched.length > 0
    ? item.name.replace(new RegExp(inputText, 'gi'), (match) => {
        return `<span>${match}</span>`
      })
    : item.name) }}>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! That was quick and it works too ;-) I still don't understand why my solution wasn't working but hey, I've just learned something new. Thank you.